# Run function from Tampermonkey button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

To get better at Javascript I am writing a Tampermonkey script for a Javascript/jQuery game. I have created a button on the page but I am unable to run any functions from it.

My question is, how would I run the functions from the button I've added to the page?

This is what I have so far:

```
var w = unsafeWindow;
var $ = w.$;

$('#quest_form').append('<button id="autoGrind" name="autoGrind" onClick="autoGrind()">Auto Grind</button>');


var e = document.getElementById("quest_destination");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

function autoGrind(){
    w.alert('Grind Started on Map: ' + strUser);
    w.setInterval(grind(), 1000);
}

function grind(){
    if(w.quest.weAreQuestingRightNow != false) { return; }
    if(w.quest.tiredTime != 0) { return; }
    quest.begin(true);
}
```

Also, I need a way to run the function `grind()` endlessly. I'm not sure if `setInterval()` is exactly what I expected it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have found a solution to your problem yet, but after many hours of struggling to get a solution that:

1. is easy enough for a beginner (me)
2. portable between Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey
3. and looks like something I might be able to do....

I got this working:

```
function addBtn() {    
    $("#quest_form").each(
        function () {          
            $(this).before("<input type='button' value='Auto Grind' id='autoGrind'>");
            $('autoGrind').click(autoGrind());
        }
    );    
}
addBtn();
```

Just four notes regarding this solution:

1. I custom made it for ME, so it might not work perfectly for you
2. I'm **VERY** new to JS so if I used bad "grammar", I'm sorry.
3. The .each won't be necessary, I had to add LOTS of buttons (removed the code dealing with their ID's).
4. I used `.before()` but `.append()` should work for you as well.

Normally I wouldn't submit an answer here since I don't know enough, but I had an identical issue, so thought I'll share my experience.

Good luck